# Customize GoogleMap from IOS API

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm looking to customize the display of a Google map. Currently I'm using the 1.13.2 ios API but I'm fairly stuck. I need something close to mapType = kGMSTypeNormal but I must get rid of shaded areas, road names, and road numbers.

Can anyone tell me where I can get the source code for the ios API or suggest a strategy for removing these layers/views on the fly without modifying the source?

If someone knows anything better that Gmaps I'm open to suggestions. I must have building shapes and road icons as the app is designed to work with the building shapes. I'd use the Apple Map framework but it doesn't show the building outlines. Think Pokémon Go, but you are cataloging buildings.

Comment: Did you solve the issue john?

Comment: No, I abandoned the project.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#introduction) offers some simple ways for you to add shapes to your maps. You are able to modify the appearance of each shape in a number of ways.

The following shapes are supported:

- A polyline is a series of connected line segments that can form any shape you want and can be used to mark paths and routes on the map.
- A polygon is an enclosed shape that can be used to mark areas on the map.
- A circle is a geographically accurate projection of a circle on the Earth's surface.

Polylines allow you to draw lines on the map. A [GMSPolyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_polyline) object represents an ordered sequence of locations, displayed as a series of line segments. You can set the color of a polyline with GMSStrokeStyle.

To customize a polylin, use `GMSPolyline`. It provides several properties to control the appearance of the line. It support the following options:

- `strokeWidth`
- `strokeWidth`
- `geodesic`
- `spans`
- `strokeColor`

You can customize your map with one of several map types. A map's type governs the overall representation of the map. The Google Maps SDK for iOS offers the following [types of maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#map_types):

- `Normal` Value: kGMSTypeNormal
- `Hybrid` Value: kGMSTypeHybrid
- `Satellite` Value: kGMSTypeSatellite
- `Terrain` Value: kGMSTypeTerrain
- `None` Value: kGMSTypeNone

To set the type of a map, assign a new value to the GMSMapView.mapType property. For example, to display a satellite map type:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.8683
longitude:151.2086
zoom:6];
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
```

Comment: Good reference for people viewing the question, but doesn't shed any light on removing items already present on a map type.